# App Script COUNTIF for maximum date in column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of dates in column A:

```
Column A
2022-02-28
2022-02-28
2022-02-28
2022-02-14
2022-02-14
2022-02-07
```

I'm trying to write a script that counts the number of times the largest date occures.  I wrote the below script

```
function maxcount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var devdeploy = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var Avals = devdeploy.getRange("A2:A").getValues();  
  var Alength = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var max = Avals[0][0]
  var unique_count = 0

  for (i=0; i < Alength; i++){
    if (Avals[i][0] == max){
      unique_count++;
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(unique_count) 
}
```

This script works if I use integer values and have the maximum value in cell A2.  However, when I use dates instead of integers it always returns a value of 1.  Any ideas on why the if loop does not work on dates, but works on integers/strings?  Also is there a way to improve the script to look for the maximum value in column A then find how many times it occurs?

Answer (score 2):

If your date in the column "A" is the date object, how about the following modification? I thought that in your script, by `var max = Avals[0][0]`, only 1st element is compared. And, if the values of column "A" are the date object, the date object is compared. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

#### Modified script:

```js
function maxcount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var devdeploy = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var Avals = devdeploy.getRange("A2:A" + devdeploy.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([a]) => a.toString() != "");
  var values = Avals.map(([a]) => a.getTime());
  var max = Math.max(...values);
  var unique_count = values.filter(v => v == max).length;
  console.log(unique_count)
}
```

- In this modification, the values are converted to the unix time, and retrieved the maximum value. And, the number of the maximum value can be retrieved.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)